# Twilio Lookup API is not returning value in java

Tags: twilio

As part of our project we need to call Twilio to get E164 format of the Phone Number. In order to do that I followed the below steps to achieve. If the phone number is valid then the below step is working but if the phone number is not valid and we are passing the same to Twillo then it is not returning anything back and halt the process.

I know that the below mention number is not valid but that doesn't mean when I am trying to lookup with invalid number it should not return any response. It should return at least an error but actually it is not which is making me more confused. I am trying with IBM websphere server.

Can some one please help me to fix this issue or is there any way where I can set request time out for twilio lookup so that it will allow other process to continue if any failures in twilio lookup. Also, correct me if I did any mistake in my coding for twilio lookup.

```
Sample URL "https://lookups.twilio.com/v1/PhoneNumbers/phoneNumber"

Steps Followed:
LookupsClient client = new LookupsClient(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN);
client.setHttpClient(getProxyClient());

// Twilio Lookup with country code
String twilioURL = createURL(phoneNumber, countryCd);
String twilioE164Number = getTwilioNumber(client, twilioURL);

//Twilio Lookup without country code 
StringBuilder appender = new StringBuilder();
appender.append(TWILIO_URL);
appender.append(PLUS);
appender.append(phoneNumber);
String twilioE164Number = getTwilioNumber(client, appender.toString());

//Create lookup URL
private String createURL(String phoneNumber, String countryCode){

        StringBuilder appender = new StringBuilder();
        appender.append(phoneNumber);
        appender.append(QUERY_PARAM);
        appender.append(countryCode);
        return TWILIO_URL+appender.toString();
}

//Get Twilio E164 Number
private String getTwilioNumber(LookupsClient client,String url){
        TwilioRestResponse response;
        String twilioResult = "";
        try {
            response = client.get(url);
                       String str = response.getResponseText();
                       //Code for parsing the JSON response and set the twilioResult.
                } catch (TwilioRestException e) {
            logger.error("TwilioRestException while calling twilio "+e);
        }catch(Exception ex){
            logger.error("Error in twilio Calling "+ex);
        }
        return twilioResult;
    }

//Get proxy client to set.
private HttpClient getProxyClient() {
        HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost(PROXY_HOST, PROXY_PORT);
        //new DefaultHttpClient().getParams().setParameter(arg0, arg1)
        DefaultProxyRoutePlanner routePlanner = new DefaultProxyRoutePlanner(proxy);
        CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
        credentialsProvider.setCredentials(new AuthScope(AuthScope.ANY_HOST, AuthScope.ANY_PORT),new UsernamePasswordCredentials(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN));
        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
                .setRoutePlanner(routePlanner)
                .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
                .build();
        return httpClient;

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

v6.3.0 of twilio-java has a [LookupsClient](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-java/blob/twilio-java-sdk-6.3.0/src/main/java/com/twilio/sdk/LookupsClient.java#L20-L22) has a `.getPhoneNumber()` method that allows you to pass a phone number instead of requiring that you construct the URL from scratch.  The whole point of using LookupsClient instead of a vanilla [TwilioClient](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-java/blob/twilio-java-sdk-6.3.0/src/main/java/com/twilio/sdk/TwilioClient.java#L520-L539) is that the class does the bulk of the work for you.

Have you tried `client.getPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)` in this case?  [This page](https://www.twilio.com/lookup) also demonstrates the structure of the response that you should receive when using that particular endpoint.  The E164-formatted phone number should be the `phone_number` property in the response, although I use twilio-python and I don't know how the Java library exposes response objects for your consumption.

If you aren't getting a response at all, you might want to try making the same request without your proxy configuration to make sure the proxy isn't causing the problem.  As for your timeout question, twilio-java's requests are processed synchronously, one way to get around that would be to wrap the request in an asynchronous method call.

Hope some of this helps you diagnose your issue!

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your suggestions. I have tried with client.getPhoneNumber(phoneNumber) also but same issue there. No response is getting from Twilio. If I remove the proxy then twilio call will not happen so proxy is needed and it is working with proxy for valid phone number. Our scenario is like we have 1000 phone number in a particular thread and for each phone number we need to call twilio to get E164 format. The number may or may not valid. If the number is valid then it is working perfectly but if not then twilio is not returning anything back and halt the process.